# pkgconf can't find a pc file even though it exists in the search path

Tags: include, shared-libraries, pkg-config, compiler-options

I have this `my.pc` file in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=/usr
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: my
Desctiption: My awesome library
Version: 0.0.1

Libs: -L${libdir} -lmy
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

pkgconf reports that it looks in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`: (result of `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config`)

```
/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

but I still get this error when I run `pkgconf --libs my`:

```
Package my was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `my.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'my', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

Answer (score 0):

pkg-config confusingly reports a missing .pc file for malformed .pc files.

In my case, I mistyped `Desctiption` instead of `Description` (replace t with r).